# Container component isn't getting props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Looking for some help, I'm pretty stuck. I apologize if my question is unclear or if I asked this question in the wrong area.

I'm working on a redux app, everything seems to work ok until the page hits map over 'sellers', and i get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined." This is my container, where it stops working:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import SellerInfo from '../components/SellerInfo';
import { getSellers } from '../actions/sellers';

class Sellers extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSellers()
  }

  render() {
    const {sellers, match} = this.props;

    return(
      <div className="seller-page">
         <div className="seller-info">
           <h1>Sellers List</h1>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div className="seller-section">
          <h3 className="seller-instructions">Click on a Seller items for sale!</h3>

          <div className="seller-section">
          <h3 className="seller-instructions">Click on a seller to see their available inventory.</h3>
            {sellers.map(seller => <SellerInfo key={seller.id} supplier={seller} />)}

        </div>
        <div className="show-seller" id="show-seller">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
  };

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    sellers: state.sellers
  })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getSellers })(Sellers);
```

actions:

```
const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

const setSellers = sellers => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_SELLERS_SUCCESS',
    sellers
  }
}

export const getSellers = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/sellers`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(sellers => dispatch(setSellers(sellers)))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const SellerInfo = ({ seller }) =>
  <div key={seller.id} id="seller-card">
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> {seller.name}</p>
    <p><strong>Location:</strong> {seller.location}</p>
  </div>


export default SellerInfo;
```

store:

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware
} from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import sellersReducer from './reducers/sellers';

const middleware = [thunk];

export default createStore(
  sellersReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```

I'm using a rails api for the data, and I can see in the Redux DevTools that the state shows my sellersReducer with all of the correctly fetched json from the database. But it says undefined when trying to map. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

`sellers` can be undefined until it returns from the store.  Try changing the line to this to check for an undefined.

```
{(sellers || []).map(seller => <SellerInfo key={seller.id} supplier={seller} />)}
```

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of the error. However, the data still won't display on the page. Any other advice? Thank you again

Comment: Add `console.log(sellers)` in `render()` of the `Sellers` component after the line `const {sellers, match} = this.props;`.  Does `sellers` have anything in it after the page stops loading?

Comment: It prints 'undefined' with the console.log(sellers)

Comment: No, it does not. I can see the data in the 'state' on devtools, but it doesn't reach the component from what I can tell